# How to create a new table row after every 4 cells within a forloop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to use the modulus operator to achieve this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>

for (i = 0; i < someVar.length; i++) {

   if (i % 4) document.write('</tr><tr>');

   document.write('<td>Hi</td>'+i):

}

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Almost. Step through the code in your head and track the values of `i` and `i % 4` as they change. Also consider that `(i % 4)` evaluates to `true` in the conditional only when its result is non-zero. I am not going to write an answer because the solution is rather simple and I want you to figure it out on your own.

Comment: @Tomalak: good idea, but sorry, I wrote my response simultaneously :-)

Comment: you should also replace `+i):` for `);` in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
<tr>

for (i = 0; i < someVar.length; i++) {

   document.write('<td>Hi</td>'+i);

   if (i % 4 == 3) document.write('</tr><tr>');

}

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(i%4==3) document.write('</tr><tr>');
```

and after the for loop, there should be something what adds empty cells to the last row, i.e.

```
while(i++%4!=0) document.write('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="tabid" border="1" >
<script  language="javascript1.1" type="text/javascript" >

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

   if (i % 4==0) document.write('</tr><tr>');

   document.write('<td>Hi'+i+'</td>');

}
</script>
</table>
```

Works fine for me

Comment: This leaves the table with an empty row at the start of it.

Comment: @tom  i tried and works fine . I edited the code and post the working code

Comment: Now you're missing a closing `</tr>`. "works fine" for you, now, on your browser isn't a good metric for web development. Write your pages to validate to standards, and _then_ test thoroughly. Now that I think about it, it's probably invalid to have a script tag inside a table.

Comment: Am using IE8 and FF3.6 Are these not good browsers!. I accept the point of standards but i just answer the question. you did not advice the questioner that this is a wrong practise :-)

Comment: Two browsers is hardly a thorough test. And, as I said, your code does not generate the closing `</tr>`, which is illegal in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write("<td>Example</td>");
    if (i % 4 == 3) {
        document.write("</tr><tr>");
    }
}
```

See  example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UeThn/28/